# How to set variables in between spaces?

Tags: c

I'm trying to set a new variable for each new "word" in a user input, despite how many words they type. For example, if someone were to type `red green blue`, I'd want variable A=red, B=green, and C=blue. What I've tried so far is

```
char a[64];
char b[64];
char c[64];
scanf("%s%s%s", a, b, c);
printf("%s%s%s", a, b, c);
```

Although it hangs until the user inputs three words. How would I go about resolving this?

Sincerely,

***NullUsxr***

Comment: That works, the variables will be set. The program will hang until they get three words because you're using a single `scanf` to get three words. Do you want it so they type one word and immediately get output? Use three `scanf`s.

Comment: well if I use three `scanf`s, the user would have to type three individual words. I want it to not matter how many words they type, as long as each one is set as an individual variable.

Comment: Use `fgets` to read a line, and `sscanf` to extract the words. The return value from `sscanf` will indicate the number of words the user entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know how many words you need to store, you also don't know how many variables you'll need. You can't store the words in individual variables, store them in an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_WORDS 64
#define MAX_WORD_LEN 64

int main()
{
    // Allocate space for 64 words of 64 characters, plus the null byte.
    // Initialize the array to 0.
    char words[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LEN+1] = {{0}};
    
    // Loop until you see the max words you can.
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_WORDS; i++) {
        printf("word? ");
        
        // If they don't input a word, stop looping.
        // They'll have to hit ctrl-d to end input.
        if( scanf("%64s", words[i]) < 1 ) {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Print the words.
    // Loop either up to the max, or until a NULL.
    for(int i = 0; words[i] && i < MAX_WORDS; i++) {
        printf("%s ", words[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

If you want to do this on a single line you can use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read the line and [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) to break it up into words ([tokenize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Token)). But, again, you'll need to use an array.

This time we don't have to allocate space for the words, `strtok` uses the memory of the string it is tokenizing. We only need space to store pointers to the words.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_WORDS 64

int main()
{
    // Allocate space for 64 words.
    // Initialize the array to 0.
    char *words[MAX_WORDS] = {0};

    // Read a line.
    char line[BUFSIZ];
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);

    char *word;
    int i;
    for(
        // Get the first word.
        word = strtok(line, " "), i = 0;
        // Stop when there are no more words
        // Or you're out of space to store them.
        word != NULL && i < MAX_WORDS;
        // Continue to break the line into words.
        word = strtok(NULL, " "), i++
    ) {
        words[i] = word;
    }

    // the rest is the same
}
```

Real programs use a library such as [`ncurses`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) to manage input and output.

Comment: @NullUsxr I updated the answer to demonstrate getting words from a single line.

Comment: May want to include `'\n'` in the delimiter, e.g. `" \n"` to strip the `'\n'` from the final token due to inclusion by `fgets()`.